# PlayOnLinux won't install?

Tags: apt, software-installation, dependencies, playonlinux

I'm running 12.04 LTS, and whenever I try to install PlayOnLinux, I keep getting this error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 playonlinux : Depends: python-wxgtk2.8 but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mesa-utils but it is not going to be installed
 primus-libs-ia32 : Depends: primus-libs but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I previously installed Bumblebee and Primus so I could optimize my games on Steam.

Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was that package `playonlinux` has dependencies those have its own dependencies. So add the `not going to be installed` packages to the main installation list.

```
sudo apt-get install playonlinux python-wxgtk2.8 mesa-utils primus-libs
```